# Webbrowser calls iframes as empty

Tags: asp.net, iframe, webbrowser-control

I am using a web browser for a ticket sales system. After I login to the system, I fill out the form to send the request for the ticket, but some problem occurs.

The browser sends the request succesfully, but when the ticket page is loading, the browser calls `iframes` as empty. I can't see the existence of `iframes` and unfortunately, iframes include the result of the request. I thought calls include the ticket, but the boss does not want it.

[image: Ticket form]

I want the result to be displayed in the iframe.
I just use `Webbrowser1.Navigate("pageurl")` for calling the request form page. After that I filled out the form and click the submit button programmatically:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sbmtBTN").invokeMember("click");
```

How can I solve It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Before I call the the page, Blocked main page of Iframe. I re-call the pages with their main pages and iframes run.